# Django URL to View mapping

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a viewset and some methods in it and getschedule is one of them.

```
def getschedule(self, request):
```

In the urls.py if I map the method getschedule like this

```
url(r'^event/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/getschedule/$', EventSingleViewSet.getschedule, name='event-schedule'),
```

I get this error ***"getschedule() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
"***

But if I do the mapping like this,

```
url(r'^event/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/getschedule/$', event_getschedule, name='event-schedule'),
......
event_getschedule = EventViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'getschedule'
}, renderer_classes=[JSONRenderer])
```

it works and gives me a response.

I don't understand how the request is getting passed to the method in the second approach. Need help understanding this.

I would also like to know how i could make my first approach work.

Comment: What is a viewset? It looks like you are mixing up [class-based](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) and [procedural](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view) views.

Comment: @solarissmoke - A viewset is a view that doesn't handle http requests, but enables read and update.  It's part of the [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/).

Comment: I think you should try this in `urls.py`:
`from <app>.views.EventSingleViewSet import getschedule as getEventSchedule`, then use it as one variable name, without the dot operator, in place of `EventSingleViewSet.getschedule`. If it works, then it's just the accepted syntax of `urlpatterns` getting in your way.

Comment: @JordonBirk I tired it. I now got the error <app>.views is not a package

Comment: Just to be sure -- for <app>, I meant to fill in the blank of what your django app is called, in place of what's bracketed. I don't know what the name of your app is.

Nonetheless, if you still get the error, anyway, then it's very likely because urls just doesn't accept a particular syntax.

Comment: @JordonBirk lol. I know that it is the app name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your viewset already is tied to a router then you can use

@detail_route, or @list_route to point it to a url with the name of your viewset method.

Check this part of documentation : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/

Otherwise, it would make sense to use plan view class extending APIView and pointing a URL to it.

Viewsets are mainly useful when tied to a router.

Comment: Using it in the router directly like this "router.register(r'event/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/getschedule/', EventViewSet.getschedule, base_name='event-schedule')" worked for me

Comment: I also would like to know if I could map the URL through the first approach mentioned in my question.

Comment: yes you can. ---

urlpatterns += [url(r'full_path_here/$', YourViewSet.as_view({'get': 'method_name'}))]